# Dataframe sorting on product name - jupiter notebook

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel document with the following columns:
number, name, street, time, day, product 1, product 2, ..... , product 40
I have imported this with:
 `df = pd.read_excel('Filename.xlsm', sheet_name="input")`

Then i have made a excel file for each product which sorts it on day and time

`productname= df['number', 'name', 'street', 'day', 'time', 'product 1']`

`productname1= productname.dropna(subset=['product 1'])`

`productname2= productname1.sort_values(by=['day', 'time'], ascending=True, inplace=False))`

`productname2.to_excel('product_1.xlsx', index=False, sheet_name='product_1')`

this is then repeated for all products in the excel file. and also some other different things but that is not important.
I know it can be looped but for keeping organised it works since products are added and subtracted from time to time and the people that have to maintain the system don't know much about coding.

My question now is that i want to have a excel file with as columns:
number, name, street, time, day, Product_name (so product 1 or product 10 f.e.), product value (so what is written for that product).

and this needs to be sorted in the same way on day and time but then also on product name this cannot be mixed up
[See the example image][1]

I am very stuck with how to achieve this, is there anybody that is able to help me?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmhb0.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to get your expected output.

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Filename.xlsm', sheet_name="input")

out = (df.melt(['number','name', 'street', 'time', 'day'], 
         var_name='product name', 
         value_name='product value')
 .dropna(subset='product value')
 .sort_values(by=['product name', 'day', 'time'], ascending=True)
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

##### `>>> display(out)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining me, i have never heard of melt but it was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: You’re welcome. Glad te be helpful.

Comment: Just some questions about the code since i am trying to understand it , What is the function of reset_index and why would i want to include this? 

then another question now the items ar not sorted, i first want to have it sorted by product name So first rows are product 1, then product 2 etc. 

Within this i want to have it sorted by day and time, i have an example sheet here but it is kind of random.

Comment: With this link you can have an example Excel file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EqD7Gm4hax9FvR59Y_31czbcvX2HdYzf/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106972328159517349233&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I think i have found it: 
I can do 
df.sort_values(by=['product name', 'day', 'time'], ascending=True, inplace=True)

Comment: Try to remove `.reset.index(drop=True)` and see the difference. And yeah, to sort the values, that's exactly the line we need to add. I updated my answer, check it out ;)

Comment: Thank you for your update, now It does exactly what I want to do. On to the next task! But I can't seem to find the difference between reset.index. Can you highlight this?